# ASP.Net Core 2.0 Shutdown Timeout, what issues can I expect using a very long time out of 2 min?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

One of our API servers processes short Cell Phone Videos and the Background process can take up to a min.

I am aware of best practices regarding moving this to a WebJob and or using Hangfire.

For the hypothetical solution of performing this task on our API Server(It just waits for Azure Media Services by polling unfortunately, so not CPU bound).

What are the pitfalls of using a very long Shutdown Timeout as described in:

- [Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)
- [Host configuration values - Shutdown Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#shutdown-timeout)

Looking for more than just opinion based answers such as "Its bad practice to do that in ASP.Net".  This configuration exists for a reason and I would like to understand the actual drawbacks.

~Thx