# .NET Core Delay vs Schedule

Tags: c#, .net-core, task, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I am trying to run a Background Scheduled Task (in a Console App) after x minutes and I can easily achieve it using `Task.Delay`. But, what is the advantaged of using a Task Scheduler?

**EDIT**: BTW, I do not have any special requirements, just want to understand why one is better than the other. A Task Scheduler requires a lot of code, so why is worth the Scheduler Task?

This is an example that I am following: https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html

Comment: Doesn't that depend on your use case?

Comment: @John No, I do not have any special requirements just want o understand why one is better than the other.

Comment: By chance can you link to or give a code example of a Scheduler Task.  I'm not familiar with it and a quick google didn't show an obvious result for me.

Comment: @ttugates please see this example: https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Delay` does what it says on the tin and thats about it.

The `IScheduledTask`/`IHostedService` implementation provides a couple of features.

1. You have a self contained class that can have dependencies injected to run the code in its own scope.
2. `IHostedService` provides a mechanism for graceful shutdown. In an ASP.NET application, the app can be recycled, you don't have a guarantee that the code you called `Task.Delay(1000*60)` on will execute.  With `IScheduledTask` solution, you implement the `StopAsync()` method to provide a graceful cancellation of the Task.  You can also configure the Host Configuration Shutdown Timeout.

Your question is regarding a console application and it appears from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/index?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#shutdown-timeout) as of .Net Core 2.1 the WebHost will be replaced with Generic Host and as such will no longer pertain specifically to ASP.NET.

*Tangent*: I have a related question  [ASP.Net Core 2.0 Shutdown Timeout, what issues can I expect using a very long time out of 2 min?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371737/asp-net-core-2-0-shutdown-timeout-what-issues-can-i-expect-using-a-very-long-ti)
 <- I have not had any issues in Production with a time out of 2 min.